# Average variation points

Tags: mean, coefficient-of-variation

Having a score board

```
        Points
Day 1   1000
Day 2   1050
Day 3   1010
Day 4   1010
Day 5   1030
```

How to calculate the average variation points? i.e. How many points, on average, a person gains or loses per day.

This must be something really simple. Yet, I can't figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Average variation points" isn't really a statistical term. For "how many points, on average, a person gains or loses per day" I can think of two answers, depending on what you mean:

$\frac{50 + 40 + 0 + 20}{4} = \frac{90}{4} = 22.5$

which treats "gains" and "losses" as absolute values and

$\frac{50 - 40 + 0 + 20}{4} = \frac{30}{4} = 9.75$

which treats them as positive and negative values.

Comment: I was hoping to find a way to calculate it without looping through the items. It works well on 5 items, but when you have a million... Thanks for pointing out that this isn't the right term. I had no idea how to call it. And thanks for fixing the grammar ;)

Comment: This would be easy to program in R or SAS.